# Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for bloqueo de librerias en mi sitio web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hace un par de horas tenia mi pagina funcionando bien sin ningún problema luego recibí una notificación de un cliente que la pagina se veía mal y revise... al inspeccionar el log de la pagina me percate de este error.
Este error lo saque de Edge

[image: Img1]

Me gustaría saber como puedo permitir que las librerías no estén bloqueadas.

Los navegadores que probe fue, OperaGX, Edge y Chrome. En los tres paso el mismo error.

[image: Img2]

Muestra el error del navegador Chrome.

Probé en 3 navegadores diferentes. Borre todo lo que tenia que ver con google analytics 4 que agregué hace poco y no funciono pensé que las librerías fueron bloqueadas por el cruce de información.
Probe de forma local sin subirlo al host y de igual forma el navegador lo tenia bloqueado. Borré las coockies de mi ordenador y pasa lo mismo.